# Problema com redirect JSF+Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho um menu onde tenho um submenu Cadastro e dentro dele um `menuItem` `Usuários` em meu Template, e também tenho um `menuItem Sair`. O problema é que o sair só funciona na tela `Home`, que é a tela que é chamada após o login. Quando entro na tela de cadastro e tendo sair o sistema não é redirecionado para pagina principal.

```
<h:form style="display: inline-block" id="frmPrincipal">
            <p:menubar styleClass="menu-sistema" id="menuBar">

                <p:submenu label="Cadastros" rendered="#{usuarioBean.usuarioLogado.cargo == 'Administrador'}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Usuários" outcome="/usuario/cadastroUsuario" />
                </p:submenu>
                <p:menuitem value="Sair" action="{usuarioBean.sair}" update=":frmPrincipal:menuBar"/>
            </p:menubar>
```

O método sair é o seguinte:

```
public String sair() {
        usuarioLogado = null;
        return "Login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mude seu método `sair()` para :

```
public void sair() {
        usuarioLogado = null;
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/Login.xhtml");
}
```

Segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w) do SOen, onde tem outras alternativas.

Comment: Não funcionou, e também se eu colocar isso no meu método que retorna uma String da erro.

Comment: No seu <p:menuitem> coloque ajax = "false".

Comment: beleza, vou tentar

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, o `usuarioLogado ` recebe null porém a pagina não é redirecionada

Comment: O sair só funciona normalmente na pagina Home

Comment: Enfim, usei uma das opções que estão no link que voce me enviou e funcionou. Obrigado